# Is there a way to delete the content under selected headers, but not the headers (and subheaders) themselves?

Tags: org-mode, regular-expressions, text-editing

Is there a way to delete the content under selected headers, but not the headers (and subheaders) themselves?

I.e.,

```
** TOC

*** PART 1: VECTORS AND GRAPHICS

[[https://livebook.manning.com/book/math-for-programmers/chapter-2?origin=product-toc][READ IN LIVEBOOK]]
**** [[https://livebook.manning.com/book/math-for-programmers/chapter-2?origin=product-toc][2DRAWING WITH 2D VECTORS]]

[[https://livebook.manning.com/book/math-for-programmers/chapter-3?origin=product-toc][READ IN LIVEBOOK]]
```

to

```
** TOC
*** PART 1: VECTORS AND GRAPHICS
**** [[https://livebook.manning.com/book/math-for-programmers/chapter-2?origin=product-toc][2DRAWING WITH 2D VECTORS]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to do that:

I collect each heading, then replace the buffer with just the headings. This also preserves properties on headlines:

```
(defun strip-headings ()
  (interactive)
  (setf (buffer-string)
    (string-join
     (cl-loop for headline in
          (org-element-map (org-element-parse-buffer) 'headline 'identity)
          collect
          (progn
            (goto-char (org-element-property :begin headline))
            (buffer-substring  (point) (progn (org-end-of-meta-data) (point)))))
     "\n")))
```

Answer (score 0):

It just occurred to me that I can do this with PCRE easily:

`perl -ne '/^(?!\*+).*\S+.*/ || print'`

I'd still like to see a structural solution that uses org-mode's parse tree, and not regexes.